# How can I limit my templatized singleton creation and make the code very generic?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I am stuck with a problem where I want to create a templatized singleton object. Something like below

```
template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:
 static Singleton<T>& GetInstance()
 {
   static Singleton<T> singleton;
   return singleton;
 }
 void Register(T Pointer) {/* */}
 void DoWork() { /* */ }
private:
  Singleton() {}
  std::unordered_set<T> pointers;
};
```

Next goal is to get access object say through a global templatized function like this

```
template<class T>
void Register(T Pointer) {
    Singleton<T>::GetInstance().Register(Pointer);
}
```

Is there a way that for a single class Hierarchy I create one singleton object. For something like below Base and derived types both result in same singleton object.

```
class Base{
};

class Derived : public Base {
};
```

Comment: I do not understand at all what the purpose of `GetObject` is or how it is intended to be called.

Comment: The pointer is supposedly dummy here to pass on the type for singleton creation. The intention is to create one singleton object for one class hierarchy. We can think of it something like this instead of GetObject I had something like below`template<class T>
void Register(T Pointer) {
    return Singleton<T>::GetInstance().Register(Pointer);
}`

Comment: @NikhilChauhan Can you show some code demonstrating how you intent to use the function?

Comment: I will make this edit to original question to be more clearer. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Is the singleton supposed to be or contain an object of type `T`?

Comment: Why does it matter that singleton is templated? You just call `Singleton<int>::GetInstance()` or for whatever other type you want, business as usual.

Comment: If you want only one `Singleton` but call `Register` with different types, then you can template the `Register` function instead of the `Singleton` class itself. If you need a different specialization of the class template for each different type to call `Register`, then trivially you can't have only one. (And why does it matter anyway? How it is written in your question the code will work fine. It will create one singleton instance per type, but why is that a problem?)

Comment: @yeputons I want singleton to be generic enough. The singleton stores pointers. Now I want the base pointer(even if derived object) to be stored always in singleton so that I can call virtual functions.  This being the reason why I would like to have same singleton created for one class hierarchy

Comment: @NikhilChauhan Start explaining the actual problem you want to solve. Show how "_Now I want the base pointer(even if derived object) to be stored always in singleton so that I can call virtual functions._" works in your code. It seems to me that you don't really want any template at all, but simply need `Singleton` to take a `Base*` pointer to store and use instead of a variable `T*`.

Comment: @user17732522 intention is to register all objects of same hierarchy to same singleton object. that's why templatizing Register function will not work for me

Comment: Why is it not `std::unordered_set<Base*> pointers;` where `Base` is the base of all the object types to which you want to store pointers? Then you don't need a template at all.

Comment: @user17732522 I can have a different class hierarchy not derived from Base but Base2 but still would like to use same infra

Comment: Why don't you just call `Singleton<Base>::GetInstance()` inside `Derived` class? Like, you have to access the singleton somehow inside the class, and then you know what singleton to access, in compile time.

Comment: Then you only need to have `T` be `BaseN*` where `BaseN` is the n-th hierarchy's root. But you need to tell `Register` somewhere to which `BaseN` the passed pointer belongs as a base. Class hierarchies do not have unique deepest bases, so this is not something that can be automatically determined, even in theory. And even with the additional assumption of a unique deepest base per hierarchy, it would still be difficult (and probably in some cases impossible) to have it be determined automatically within C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to introduce a new base class to your heiratchy that handles the registration and rely on CRTP to ensure that the instances are registered with the correct singleton. First we'll clean up the `Singleton` itself so that the `Register` takes a pointer instead of a plain type of `T`.

```
template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:

    static Singleton<T>& GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton<T> singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

    void Register(T* /*Pointer*/) {/* */ }
};
```

Now we'll introduce a new templated base class with a single type argument which handles the registration with the singleton based on the type it's passed. This will be used as the base class for `Base` (in your sample code).

```
template<class T>
struct Registerable
{
    virtual ~Registerable() = default;

    virtual void Register() final
    {
        std::cout
            << "Singleton @ "
            << &Singleton<T>::GetInstance()
            << "\n";

        Singleton<T>::GetInstance().Register(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
};
```

I've marked the `Register` function as `virtual` and `final` to prevent derived classes from overriding it. I've also added a single log to `cout` so that we can track which singleton is being used for registration. Now all that we need to do is have `Base` derive from `Registerable` and pass `Base` as the template argument (CRTP).

```
struct Base : Registerable<Base>
{
    // ....
};
```

The classes that derive from `Base` remain unchanged as there's nothing extra for them to do.

```
struct Derived : public Base {};
struct OtherDerived : public Derived {};
```

And now we'll run a little test code to see what happens.

```
int main()
{
    Base base;
    Derived derived;
    OtherDerived otherDerived;

    base.Register();
    derived.Register();
    otherDerived.Register();
}
```

And our output is:

```
Singleton @ 0015C75C
Singleton @ 0015C75C
Singleton @ 0015C75C
```

I don't have a lot of details on how you plan to use this so how you mold it to what you're trying to accomplish is up to you.

Note that you also have the option of making `Registerable` an inner class of `Singleton`. This allows you make the `Register` function in `Singleton` private in order to prevent it from being directly used.

```
template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:

    struct Registerable
    {
        virtual ~Registerable() = default;

        virtual void Register() final
        {
            std::cout
                << "Singleton @ "
                << &Singleton<T>::GetInstance()
                << "\n";

            Singleton<T>::GetInstance().Register(static_cast<T*>(this));
        }
    };

    static Singleton<T>& GetInstance()
    {
        static Singleton<T> singleton;
        return singleton;
    }

private:

    void Register(T* /*Pointer*/) {/* */ }
};
```

If you do this the `Base` class changes only slightly.

```
struct Base : Singleton<Base>::Registerable
{
    // ....
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks like something I am trying to achieve. Will give this a try.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested and it worked like a cake. I have edited the question with entire code and stuck in one part. If you could please help out with that. It would be really great

Comment: @NikhilChauhan That's great that everything is getting closer to what you like but I suggest that you revert your edit and post a new question (refer to your original if you like). The reason for this is that the current answers no longer reflect the original question and likely to confuse others. Make sure to pose the new question with the specific problem you are trying to solve rather than just looking for general improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define special type in all your bases and then use that type to determine base of hierarchy. Something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

static int count = 0;

template<class T>
class Singleton {
public:
 static Singleton<T>& GetInstance()
 {
   static Singleton<T> singleton;
   std::cout << "Singleton: " << &singleton << std::endl;
   return singleton;
 }
 void Register(T Pointer) {/* */}
 void DoWork() { /* */ }
 void Print() {std::cout << "Singleton: " << num << std::endl;}
private:
  Singleton() : num(count++) {}
  int num;
};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct BaseType {using type = T;};
template<typename T>
struct BaseType<T, std::void_t<typename std::remove_pointer_t<T>::SingletonBase>> {using type = typename std::remove_pointer_t<T>::SingletonBase *;};

template<class T>
void Register(T Pointer) {
    Singleton<BaseType<T>::type>::GetInstance().Register(Pointer);
}

class Base{
public:
    using SingletonBase = Base;
};

class Derived : public Base {
};

class Base1 {
public:
    using SingletonBase = Base1;
};

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;
    Base1 b1;
    Derived1 d1;
    int i;
    Register(&b);
    Register(&d);
    Register(&b1);
    Register(&d1);
    Register(&i);
}
```